# TRYING to get the output SQL and adapt to excel SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, powerquery

I have this table that I called (t)

| fecha | employee | motive | descrip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | PETER | B | baja |
| 01/01/2022 | MARY | R | ruta |
| 01/01/2022 | ANN | R | ruta |
| 02/01/2022 | PETER | B | baja |
| 02/01/2022 | MARY | R | ruta |
| 02/01/2022 | ANN | R | ruta |
| 03/01/2022 | PETER | B | baja |
| 03/01/2022 | MARY | R | ruta |
| 03/01/2022 | ANN | R | ruta |
| 04/01/2022 | PETER | R | ruta |
| 04/01/2022 | MARY | R | ruta |
| 04/01/2022 | ANN | R | ruta |
| 05/01/2022 | PETER | R | ruta |
| 05/01/2022 | MARY | R | ruta |
| 05/01/2022 | ANN | R | ruta |
| 06/01/2022 | PETER | B | baja |
| 06/01/2022 | MARY | R | ruta |
| 06/01/2022 | ANN | R | ruta |

and want to get this output

| employee | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PETER | 01/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 |
| PETER | 06/01/2022 | 06/01/2022 |

Also I need to run the query in Excel vba editor

My attempt doesn't get to the output

```
select 
    employee, min(fecha), max(fecha)
from
    (select 
         t.*,
         lag(motive) over (partition by employee order by fecha) as prev_motive,
         lead(motive) over (partition by employee order by fecha) as next_motive,
         sum(case when motive = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employee order by fecha) as num_b
     from t) t
where 
    motive = 'B' 
    and (prev_motive <> 'B' or prev_motive is null) 
    and (next_motive <> 'B' or next_motive is null)
group by 
    employee, num_b;
```

```
select 
    employee, min(fecha), max(fecha)
from
    (select
         t.*,
         lag(motive) over (partition by employee order by fecha) as prev_motive,
         lead(motive) over (partition by employee order by fecha) as next_motive,
         sum(case when motive = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employee order by fecha) as num_b
     from t) t
where 
    motive = 'B' 
    and (prev_motive <> 'B') 
    and (next_motive <> 'B')
group by 
    employee, num_b;
```

Please help

Comment: Please post data as data, not picture. This could help https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables . Also please explain in words why the output should be as pictured.

Comment: Think I understand the rules producing the output. I don't think SQL alone can accomplish.

Comment: What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: you should be able to export the table from excel to text (format for windows if using windows) then cut and paste that into the stack overflow question.

Comment: Just that my attempt doesn't get to the output

Comment: You are repeating yourself but do not answer the questions being asked. I know SQL and power query are two complete different things. Is your question: Given the input data. How can I generate a result with power query what gives me the 2 rows output? Also you should explain the logic in words how you get to 2 rows.

Comment: I can edit it, the answer is no, i don't have any error message, I just that I don't know how to get output, can anybody in any way?

Comment: to repeat an earlier comment: "Also please explain in words what you are trying to do"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have obtained the Access SQL Query that yields the output and I want to share it with the entire community.

```
SELECT 
    bajas.employee,
    bajas.start_date,
    IIF(
        IsNull(MIN(regresos.next_date)), 
        (SELECT MAX(t.fecha) FROM t WHERE t.employee = bajas.employee AND t.motive = 'B' AND t.fecha >= bajas.start_date),
        DateAdd("d", -1, MIN(regresos.next_date))
    ) AS end_date
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            t1.employee,
            t1.fecha AS start_date
        FROM 
            t AS t1
        WHERE 
            t1.motive = 'B'
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM t AS t2
                WHERE 
                    t2.employee = t1.employee 
                    AND t2.fecha = DateAdd("d", -1, t1.fecha) 
                    AND t2.motive = 'B'
            )
    ) AS bajas
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            t3.employee,
            t3.fecha AS next_date
        FROM 
            t AS t3
        WHERE 
            t3.motive <> 'B'
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM t AS t4
                WHERE 
                    t4.employee = t3.employee 
                    AND t4.fecha < t3.fecha 
                    AND t4.motive = 'B'
            )
    ) AS regresos
ON 
    bajas.employee = regresos.employee AND bajas.start_date < regresos.next_date
GROUP BY 
    bajas.employee,
    bajas.start_date
ORDER BY 
    bajas.employee, 
    bajas.start_date;
```